# Rails Ancestry gem rebuild cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I'm using `gem ancestry` in a Rails3 app.

I am trying to change an existing model named sites to use the cache depth.

The documentation says this:

```
:cache_depth           Cache the depth of each node in the 'ancestry_depth' column (default: false)
                   If you turn depth_caching on for an existing model:
                   - Migrate: add_column [table], :ancestry_depth, :integer, :default => 0
                   - Build cache: TreeNode.rebuild_depth_cache!
```

I added the migration.

But, I don't understand how to execute the `- Build cache: TreeNode.rebuild_depth_cache!`

Where do I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the model that has ancestry. Example:

```
class Site
  has_ancestry cache_depth: true
end

> Site.rebuild_depth_cache!
```

Comment: Using Rails console.  The `s = Site.new` gives me `2.0.0p353 :001 > s = Site.new
 => #<Site id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, type_id: nil, tenant_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, address1: nil, address2: nil, city: nil, state: nil, zipcode: nil, ancestry: nil, position: nil, ancestry_depth: 0>`

Comment: `s.rebuild_depth_cache!` gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method `rebuild_depth_cache!' for #<Site:0x007fa000800618>`

Comment: Please change your answer to include: `has_ancestry cache_depth: true`